# How to fix ubuntu boot alongside windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub2

In the beginning I had only Ubuntu on my pc.
After I installed Win 7 in another partition.
Then Ubuntu boot doesn't starts anymore?
I need dual boot: how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add Ubuntu to your Windows boot menu with a boot manager like **EasyBCD** (freeware), or you can boot from an Ubuntu Live CD and re-install **grub**, which will recognise both W7 and Ubuntu.